# What is the limit to how much humanity can advance in the physical sciences?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I currently adopt the view of reductive physicalism. Yet, I can’t help but wonder to what limits we can understand the universe. After all, are’t these fields firmly  based on empirical evidence, which imposes limits on how well we can know what is to be known?

On top of this, mathematics is crucially important to the understanding of the scientific evidence. Is there then a limit to how much mathematics can achieve, especially in the fields of theoretical physics?

Comment: Impossible to judge because the means of making new advances are often advanced by the advance of knowledge.

Comment: Impossible to know. Concerning mathematics, it is remarkably pliable, since you can tweak the foundations and even what's under the foundations. I doubt maths will run out of steam anytime soon because of that.

Comment: This has been the subject of much discussion, just google your question, e.g., https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/limits-on-human-comprehension/ or https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-5555-3_5 or https://www.santafe.edu/news-center/news/new-proof-shows-fundamental-limits-scientific-knowledge or many, many, many others. (And note how Wolpert figures prominently in my first and third links, with the more recent third providing a proof of his earlier conjectures.)

Comment: In many fields we can distinguish between soft limits and hard limits, but even hard limits do end up being broken and it's impossible to predict. Take microscopy for instance. There has always been a "best resolution achieved so far" limit. This soft limit kept being pushed, until it reached the [hard limit 0.25 μm imposed by the diffraction of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system#The_Abbe_diffraction_limit_for_a_microscope). And then [that limit was circumvented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution_microscopy).

Comment: "How much of what we don't know are we able to know?" ("We don't know because we don't know what we don't know.")

Answer (score 10):

If the history of philosophy *and science* has taught us anything, it is that this will be hard to pin down.

After Newton, many thinkers (including Kant and Hegel) thought that we were now done with all physics of material interaction (even though there was some discussion around the nature of gravity, absolute space and time, and the aether). With Maxwell, many thinkers thought we are done with electromagnetic physics. Under very specific constrictions within certain parameters, that actually has some truth to it. And then, within three decades, the Curies, Planck, Einstein, Bohr, Schrödinger, Heisenberg, Born, and Dirac completely revolutionalised our understanding of all kinds of physical interactions and we are still catching up to what they and their successors (like Higgs) made out of this.

Now, what may be an absolute barrier of knowledge-acquisition? The trivial answer is: We just cannot know. An educated guess from current physics is rather: Energy (or at least: energy *density*). The moment we need more energy density than we can possibly or safely produce on earth within our technical and economic abilities in order to produce further states of matter to investigate, that is our current hard limit, see the discussions around the [FCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Circular_Collider) and whether it makes sense to build it in the first place. That is still plastic within limits as we technically progress but thinking this to its possible end, there is also a hard physical limit: We cannot produce energy densities on earth that will prove catastrophic to the planet itself (or large parts of it). Many interesting physical phenomena do only occur in environments that probably cannot be produced in a safe, scaled laboratory environment. That is why we are limited to *inferral* from the observation of *outcomes* of these phenomena happening lightyears away. Obviously, that *has* hard limits but considering the ingenuity of scientists, those are not reached for some decades or hundreds of years to come.

Apart from that rather *technical* limit there is also a lot of philosophical literature on an *epistemological* limit: As living organisms posited in space-time, we are limited in our ability to interact with our environment. That concept is called anthropological or hermeneutical circle, which involves both our ability to *sense* something of the universe around us at all (even if mediated through instruments) and our ability to *understand* these sensual inputs through the symbols and conceptual frameworks we possess. Even if we ever further the latter, what we still need is an *interaction* with us or things that we can interact with (directly or mediated by instruments) for something to "exist" for us. In this phenomenological thinking, existence always means existing "for us" (in a collective sense of humanity). So anything that does not interact with us or the matter we have power over and can scrutinize through instruments is in a very important sense beyond our limits. (A philosophy of nature that best covers the point of this paragraph is that of Helmuth Plessner afaik)

Comment: Sources to support the main claims would make this a good answer.

Comment: @BrianZ What do you need sources for? The fact that physics is hitting semi-hard borders (like with the immense costs and probably limited additional utility of the proposed FCC collider needed to further knowledge)? Please specify.

Comment: "the main point is that at every point in time, after every major new theory humanity thought that they now are done with it." - Is this just your interpretation or are you assuming it to be common knowledge? Did Newton or any of the others you mention explicitly say this somewhere?

Comment: Energy limitation could be only a transient, rather than an absolute limit though. I think the question is more interesting from the angle of: are there things that humans absolutely cannot know or understand, i.e. do humans have some inherent limitation to acquiring knowledge.

Comment: Not just a lack of a quantum-gravity theory: dark matter & dark energy are thought to accoint for 95% of the constituents of the universe. You could argue that our real progress is to begin uncovering the scale of our ignorance.

Comment: @BrianZ: I agree that the wording was off. Newton's **theory** of gravity was highly criticised by Berkeley and esp. Leibniz as well as Kant and others later (to no effect for hundreds of years until Mach inspired Einstein, no less). His *laws* of motion and gravity were taken as a given by all of his critics, though.

Comment: _"We cannot produce energy densities on earth that will prove catastrophic to the planet itself...."_ Oh, let's not dismiss this so quickly! Humans are ingenious, so have hope and never say never! :-)

Comment: "So anything that does not interact with us or the matter we have power over and[/or] can scrutinize through instruments is in a very important sense beyond our limits" - sure, but the advancement of technology may expand which matter we're able to "scrutinize through instruments". At any given point in time, this would only be a line in the sand, and we wouldn't know if anything even exists beyond that until we're able to find evidence of it.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Sure, yet it is a hard unknowable (and thus useless to ponder about) if there is something out there that does not interact with matter/fields **at all**.

Answer (score 5):

In physics we observe patterns, create mathematical models that conform to the patterns we observe, then test the validity of a model by checking that the predictions it makes agree with other observations. There are, therefore, two types of limiting factors that will govern what progress we make.

The first is a limit on what we can observe. This limit applies in a number of ways. We cannot observe things in detail when they are far away, and indeed events that are sufficiently far away we will never be able to observe. We cannot observe the outcome of very long-term processes (we can't see how the Universe will behave in the distant future), nor can we see further back in time than the Big-Bang. There is also a limit on the resolving power of our experiments to detect the very small, or to observe effects that require very high concentrations of energy. All of those factors limit our observations of the physical Universe.

The second is a limit on the complexity of the models we create. Almost all real physical systems are too complicated to represent faithfully as mathematical models; and some of the phenomena we encounter appear to be truly unpredictable, such as the random nature of microscopic events in the quantum field. Your brain, for example, contains countless particles interacting in a way that is far too complicated for us, currently, to model at that level of detail.

Comment: But for the complexity of models, we now have computers, we do phenomenological simulations etc etc. I think there is a still a lot of runway, maybe at the expense - true - of producing a semi-simple differential equation that would give insights like they used to do before the advent of computers. Maybe the nature/quality of our understanding is changing as we rely more and more on computers.

Comment: "nor can we see further back in time than the Big-Bang" - based on our current understanding, we can't. But people from the past couldn't trace the history of the universe back that far, so it's not inconceivable that people from the future would be able to trace it back further.

Answer (score 4):

The limits of progress in empirical science go beyond what can be inferred by pure reason because it involves a myriad of parameters related to economy and physics. In the end, it is the circumstances of our observations that determine what we can observe.

For example, suppose we can't manage to find a replacement for our depleted fossil fuels, rising the price and rarity of energy to unprecedented levels. It's probable we would have to kiss a lot of our research programs bye bye in order to focus on survival. That would include particle accelerators, so no more progress in particle physics. The same could be said about medical research: it is our affluence as a society that allows for people specializing in long and costly data gathering in proper conditions. If we were to run out of disposable syringe, gloves, etc that would no doubt put a hard restraint on what research could be conducted. Let's not even talk about computers, heavy consumers of resources and absolutely necessary to any modern research.

There are speculations about how a slightly different world would have impacted our ability to understand it. For exemple, computations have been done showing that if the Earth had been a bit more massive we wouldn't have been able to build rockets powerful enough to reach orbit (a bigger rocket wouldn't do, we'd need more powerful engines, made in materials yet unknown to use, etc), or make their cost so prohibitive that we would have been practically limited to stay on the planet. That means entire domains of exploration would never have emerged.

I remember a lecture from Lawrence Krauss about the expansion of the universe. In the conclusion he conjectured that at some point this expansion will be faster than light, which means electromagnetic waves from far away stars and galaxies would cease to reach Earth. He continued by imagining a late civilization (in 1.000.000.000 years+) that would have pointed telescopes at the sky and be able to observe nothing but our own galaxy. Those people would then construct models of reality that would account for this unique galaxy alone in the void of space. Because they wouldn't be able to observe galaxies drifting away like Hubble, they for exemple would have no idea that the universe is expanding or that there eve was a big bang.

Their model would be false, because the other galaxies and the big bang would still exist, but they would have no way to get to know it. For them it would be perfectly reasonable to posit their galaxy has always existed. But the truth would be forever lost to them, unobservable.

Which leads to the question: what is our own unobservable? What evidence of the mechanics of the universe is forever lost to us in the same way the expansion of the universe is lost to this future civilization? We can't know. Maybe there is no such thing, but we can't even be sure of that.

Defining the limits of progress in science would require not only intricate knowledge about the economy of our world, but also God like prescience about things we will never be able to know.

Comment: But I think those are accidents, curve balls that the universe is throwing at us. Intrinsically, are there inherent limits to what a human can understand? For example, are we missing some category of understanding that would be needed to know something?

Comment: @Frank There are good reasons to suggest that there may well be such limits but that we can never know whether they are there because we are limited as posited, living organisms in space-time by our ability to interact with our environment. That concept is called anthropological or hermeneutical circle. What we need is an *interaction* with us or things that we can interact with (directly or mediated by instruments) for something to "exist" for us. In this phenomenological strand, existence always means existing "for us" (in a collective sense of humanity). Added in my answer...

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Agreed. Very sensible.

Comment: @Frank as Philipklocking said there are such limits, but the economic ones are more important in that they are the one we are going to meet first. Call them a "curve ball" is participating in the myth that some form of innovation will always be there to let us progress, which is not demonstrated. The last exemple about the big bang is telling, because its not even about technology: if the light does not reach us no tech will make it observable. It also put us, current humans, in a position to understand the late civilization's predicament (which they can't from their own perspective).

Answer (score 3):

Two comments.

First, about mathematics, I am skeptical that there is any "limitation" to what mathematics can deduce, since mathematics is very pliable. If we see mathematics from a formal point of view, as a game with symbols, it is very easy to change axioms and deduce "new mathematics". But beyond that, even the rules of deduction are pliable: the logic used in "First Order Logic" can be altered to allow many valued logic, etc etc. One ends up wondering what exactly is "mathematics". But I am convinced it can be adapted to anything we will encounter in nature.

Second, I think the nature of our understanding is changing since the advent of computers. These days, you may make predictions about the universe from computer simulations. The quality of the understanding obtained this way may be different from the "traditional" way which typically involved e.g. actually solving a differential equation. Now, you don't need to solve it, you can just simulate it. One could say we are obtaining a *shallower* understanding this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on the "learning all" paradigm, which makes it a little ill-formed.

Such approach has blatantly obvious limits. We don't have enough memory, time and reach to learn all. This is like going to your local library and start with the first author, "Aarset", to continue alfabetically. You see, that is a bad idea.

Our mind doesn't work with such paradigm, but with a different one: *systemic thinking*.

A system is a set of interrelated parts; systems have parts, which are also systems with parts, and simultaneously, each system is part of another, which is also a system. This makes the definition of system recursive: a system is a fractal, made by smaller systems, part of larger systems.

Now: knowledge is a system of concepts. That is, a family has members, members have names, names have letters, letters have parts... Whatever. At the same time, a family is part of a society, etc. The point to understand here is that systems can be divided into parts in multiple forms. A person can be a set of feelings, or a set of parts, it all depends on the subject, that is, systems are subjective.

Now, to the answer.

Imagine a ficticious person, John. His final goal is to survive (others might have other goals, perhaps Jane wants to be rich, whatever). John's goal is to be alive. That idea (system) implies (the set of parts): having a place to live; being healthy; having what to eat. This last idea (the smaller system) implies (the set of parts): living with others, working with others, learning from others... and so on.

So, we don't need AT ALL to learn everything (*learning all* paradigm). We need only to learn what allow each one of us to reach our goals (*systemic thinking*). I'm pretty sure you don't know how to solve a quantum mechanics wave equation. Why? Not because you can't learn it, you surely can: you don't because you don't need it. But others need to know it for their goals. Here in this forum, we want to learn philosophy, normally, to live better, to understand the world, nature, etc.

And from such perspective, what is the limit? The amount of knowledge that allows one to reach its goals. And the consequence is simple: for John, not reaching enough knowledge means to die. For Jane, to be poor.

Once goals have been reached, no need to learn more. That's why there are billions of people that have everything they need, and don't need to learn anything else, except what happens on social networks.

Comment: Yes and no. There are many mathematicians for example, who work on very abstract of e.g. algebraic geometry, which is absolutely not needed for any goal, yet they devote careers to it. It seems humans want to know/understand even when they don't need to.

Comment: But for Jane to be rich, should she not also abide by the same set of systems as John and build on top of it from there on?While this response has given a new perspective in something I never thought about, you can’t truly say that the limits of advancing in the natural sciences is purely subjective.

Comment: @LenaWena that's precisely what I state. Goal limits (what I want) are subjective, as well as capability limits (what I can). Don't think linearly, with the proper intentions an the right potentials, a single individual can lead an army of mathematicians to solve a huge equation (that's systemic thinking). Soon we'll have quantum computers, and powerful artificial intelligences. Our minds act not linearly. Just in software developmentt, some programmers can be 10k times more productive than common ones. And strictly, _one loses the day one stops trying_ (Einstein, I think). We will not stop.

Comment: @Frank lack of necessity is not the same as lack of goal. All our acts follow goals, even if those are just satisfying curiosity or to enjoy using a new pencil.

Comment: @RodolfoAP Right, and because we are very curious, and also there can be pleasure in solving esoteric maths problems, so we will never stop.

Answer (score 2):

[The Hard Problem of Consciousness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness#:%7E:text=The%20hard%20problem%20of%20consciousness,integrate%20information%2C%20and%20so%20forth.)

[Event Horizon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon)

[Ignoramus Et Ignoramibus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoramus_et_ignorabimus)

The first, *the hard problem of consciousness*, asserts the *limits* of *objectivity*, a sine qua non for science.

The second describes a limit to *observation*, another necessity for science. The limits of mathematics would be the related *black holes* and similar objects like the Big Bang in which, I hear, *infinity* pops up in the equations (we still don't have well-defined operations on infinity).

The third lists some questions that are thought to be beyond the  science-math duo - unanswerables, colorfully named **7 World Riddles**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some day the progress of physical sciences will eventually propound a concept that denies pluralism (theoretically only).

So **losing of plurality** must be the limit to how much mathematics can achieve, especially in the fields of theoretical physics.  Since all subjects need a subject, even mathematics cannot achieve go beyond this limit.

To go beyond this limit the subject must dissolve to become one with it. Then the subject and object become one.

Since numbers are essential in mathematics they are essential in theoretical physics also.  If **the same mind** is creating **number** and **numbers**, there must be a ‘One’ behind numbers (and even behind number).  Again, if those number and numbers do not  change even if counted by another person, that implies that there must be a ‘One’ to coordinate them.  That asserts the influence of ‘One’.  This actually leads us to think that, basically, even mathematics can go beyond ‘One’.  This affects everything including the ideas of point, length, area, volume etc.

If this is reasonable, here the cuff will be on theoretical physics.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean? Are you trying to suggest that because people will fight with each other, science can't advance?

Comment: Never. I meant, the advancement in humanity will not be directly proportional to the advancement in physical science.  If the advancement is only on the intellectual level, it may even become inversely proportional.

Comment: This does not answer the question whether and in which sense there may be hard limits to the progression of knowledge acquisition in natural sciences, which basically is the gist of the question.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking You are right, upon re-reading the OP, my comments about "inherent limits" may not be the gist of the OP - although a very interesting philosophical question.